# How can I add an Annotation in dygraph?

Tags: javascript, graph, annotations, dygraphs

I have the following code that displays a graph using dygraphs:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>title tbd - jsFiddle demo</title>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4rc2.js'></script>


   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css"> 
      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js"></script> 
   <style type='text/css'>   
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    var csvData = function() {
    return "Date,Close Price\n" +
        "2015-09-17,5.20\n" + 
        "2015-09-16,5.31\n" + 
        "2015-09-15,5.40\n" + 
        "2015-09-14,5.20\n" + 
        "2015-09-11,5.17\n" + 
        "2015-09-10,5.20\n" + 
        "2015-09-09,5.09\n" + 
        "2015-09-08,5.05\n" + 
        "2015-09-07,4.90\n" + 
        "2015-09-04,4.74\n" + 
        "2015-09-03,4.68\n" + 
        "2015-09-02,4.24\n" + 
        "2015-09-01,4.20\n" + 
        "2015-08-31,4.06\n" + 
        "2015-08-28,4.19\n" + 
        "2015-08-27,4.08\n" + 
        "2015-08-26,4.20\n" + 
        "2015-08-25,4.04\n" + 
        "2015-08-24,3.53\n" + 
        "2015-08-21,4.30\n" + 
        "2015-08-20,4.45\n" + 
        "2015-08-19,4.58\n" + 
        "2015-08-18,4.54\n" + 
        "2015-08-17,4.63\n" + 
        "2015-08-14,4.49\n" + 
        "2015-08-13,4.56\n" + 
        "2015-08-12,4.69\n" + 
        "2015-08-11,4.80\n" + 
        "2015-08-10,4.65\n" + 
        "2015-08-07,4.40\n" + 
        "2015-08-06,4.24\n" + 
        "2015-08-05,3.98\n" + 
        "2015-08-04,3.84\n" + 
        "2015-08-03,3.66\n" + 
        "2015-07-31,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-30,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-29,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-28,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-27,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-24,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-23,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-22,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-21,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-20,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-17,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-16,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-15,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-14,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-13,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-10,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-09,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-08,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-07,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-06,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-03,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-02,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-07-01,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-06-30,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-06-29,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-06-26,4.71\n" + 
        "2015-06-25,4.45\n" + 
        "2015-06-24,4.43\n" + 
        "2015-06-23,4.41\n" + 
        "2015-06-22,4.14\n" + 
        "2015-06-19,3.84\n" + 
        "2015-06-18,3.65\n" + 
        "2015-06-17,3.63\n" + 
        "2015-06-16,4.23\n" + 
        "2015-06-15,4.49\n" + 
        "2015-06-12,4.74\n" + 
        "2015-06-11,5.04\n" + 
        "2015-06-10,4.75\n" + 
        "2015-06-09,4.75\n" + 
        "2015-06-08,4.61\n" + 
        "2015-06-05,4.69\n" + 
        "2015-06-04,4.91\n" + 
        "2015-06-03,4.94\n" + 
        "2015-06-02,4.68\n" + 
        "2015-06-01,4.56\n" + 
        "2015-05-29,4.56\n" + 
        "2015-05-28,4.96\n" + 
        "2015-05-27,5.29\n" + 
        "2015-05-26,4.75\n" + 
        "2015-05-25,4.88\n" + 
        "2015-05-22,5.06\n" + 
        "2015-05-21,5.18\n" + 
        "2015-05-20,5.07\n" + 
        "2015-05-19,5.28\n" + 
        "2015-05-18,5.26\n" + 
        "2015-05-15,4.95\n" + 
        "2015-05-14,5.00\n" + 
        "2015-05-13,5.18\n" + 
        "2015-05-12,5.49\n" + 
        "2015-05-11,5.50\n" + 
        "2015-05-08,5.74\n" + 
        "2015-05-07,5.84\n" + 
        "2015-05-06,5.60\n" + 
        "2015-05-05,5.28\n" + 
        "2015-05-04,5.80\n" + 
        "2015-05-01,5.99\n" + 
        "2015-04-30,5.99\n" + 
        "2015-04-29,5.46\n" + 
        "2015-04-28,5.58\n" + 
        "2015-04-27,5.45\n" + 
        "2015-04-24,4.97\n" + 
        "2015-04-23,4.87\n" + 
        "2015-04-22,4.57\n" + 
        "2015-04-21,4.30\n" + 
        "2015-04-20,4.85\n" + 
        "2015-04-17,4.86\n" + 
        "2015-04-16,5.09\n" + 
        "2015-04-15,4.80\n" + 
        "2015-04-14,5.00\n" + 
        "2015-04-13,5.45\n" + 
        "2015-04-10,5.45\n" + 
        "2015-04-09,5.45\n" + 
        "2015-04-08,5.38\n" + 
        "2015-04-07,5.42\n" + 
        "2015-04-06,5.50\n" + 
        "2015-04-03,5.50\n" + 
        "2015-04-02,5.50\n" + 
        "2015-04-01,5.49\n" + 
        "2015-03-31,5.70\n" + 
        "2015-03-30,5.80\n" + 
        "2015-03-27,5.68\n" + 
        "2015-03-26,5.40\n" + 
        "2015-03-25,5.83\n" + 
        "2015-03-24,5.83\n" + 
        "2015-03-23,5.30\n" + 
        "2015-03-20,5.01\n" + 
        "2015-03-19,4.84\n" + 
        "2015-03-18,4.90\n" + 
        "2015-03-17,5.13\n" + 
        "2015-03-16,4.91\n" + 
        "2015-03-13,5.18\n" + 
        "2015-03-12,5.53\n" + 
        "2015-03-11,5.58\n" + 
        "2015-03-10,5.70\n" + 
        "2015-03-09,5.60\n" + 
        "2015-03-06,6.15\n" + 
        "2015-03-05,6.19\n" + 
        "2015-03-04,6.40\n" + 
        "2015-03-03,6.32\n" + 
        "2015-03-02,6.51\n" + 
        "2015-02-27,7.00\n" + 
        "2015-02-26,7.30\n" + 
        "2015-02-25,7.50\n" + 
        "2015-02-24,6.88\n" + 
        "2015-02-23,6.05\n" + 
        "2015-02-20,6.05\n" + 
        "2015-02-19,6.09\n" + 
        "2015-02-18,5.90\n" + 
        "2015-02-17,5.98\n" + 
        "2015-02-16,6.00\n" + 
        "2015-02-13,6.20\n" + 
        "2015-02-12,5.54\n" + 
        "2015-02-11,5.25\n" + 
        "2015-02-10,5.64\n" + 
        "2015-02-09,5.18\n" + 
        "2015-02-06,5.15\n" + 
        "2015-02-05,5.27\n" + 
        "2015-02-04,5.50\n" + 
        "2015-02-03,5.69\n" + 
        "2015-02-02,5.12\n" + 
        "2015-01-30,4.80\n" + 
        "2015-01-29,4.78\n" + 
        "2015-01-28,4.45\n" + 
        "2015-01-27,5.17\n" + 
        "2015-01-26,5.82\n" + 
        "2015-01-23,5.63\n" + 
        "2015-01-22,5.16\n" + 
        "2015-01-21,4.94\n" + 
        "2015-01-20,5.18\n" + 
        "2015-01-19,5.20\n" + 
        "2015-01-16,4.77\n" + 
        "2015-01-15,4.90\n" + 
        "2015-01-14,5.03\n" + 
        "2015-01-13,5.31\n" + 
        "2015-01-12,5.20\n" + 
        "2015-01-09,4.93\n" + 
        "2015-01-08,4.76\n" + 
        "2015-01-07,4.97\n" + 
        "2015-01-06,5.07\n" + 
        "2015-01-05,5.07\n" + 
        "2015-01-02,5.55\n" + 
        "2015-01-01,5.40\n" + 
        "2015-10-28,10";  
};

$(document).ready(function () {   

    // Get your data from somewhere
    var data = csvData();

    // Set highlight start and end
    var highlight_start = new Date('2015/09/17');
    var highlight_end = new Date('2015/10/28');  

    g = new Dygraph(
        document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
        data,
        {
            animatedZooms: true,
            underlayCallback: function(canvas, area, g) {
                var bottom_left = g.toDomCoords(highlight_start,0);
                var top_right = g.toDomCoords(highlight_end,2500); 
                console.log(bottom_left);               
                console.log(top_right);

                var left = bottom_left[0];
                var right = top_right[0];

                canvas.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 102, 1.0)";
                canvas.fillRect(left, area.y, right - left, area.h);          
  }
}          
    );



g.setAnnotations([
    {
      series: "Temperature",
      x: "2015-05-08",
      shortText: "L",
      text: "Coldest Day"
    }
    ]);


});





</script>    
</head>
<body>
  <div id="graphdiv" style="width:600px; height:300px;"></div>
<div id="div_g" style="width:600px; height:300px;"></div>
<p>When you zoom and pan, the region remains highlighted.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to add an annotation like described in http://dygraphs.com/annotations.html:

```
 g.setAnnotations([
        {
          series: "Temperature",
          x: "2015-05-08",
          shortText: "L",
          text: "Coldest Day"
        }
 ]);
```

But the annotation doesn't show up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `series` to one of your column names, e.g. `Close Price`:

```
g.setAnnotations([
    {
      series: "Close Price",
      x: "2015-05-08",
      shortText: "L",
      text: "Coldest Day"
    }
]);
```

See example here:
http://codepen.io/Dragory/pen/QjEpEK

Comment: That is working, thank you. But how can i add a second annotation?

Comment: Yes, you can add multiple objects to the array in setAnnotations. I updated the codepen with a second annotation: http://codepen.io/Dragory/pen/QjEpEK